# Postman C# code snippet working on postman and not in app

Tags: c#, xml, postman

I have an XML file that is sent as form-data to a remote server. When I use postman, I receive the response that I was supposed to receive.

[Postman response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yl12f.png)

Then I use the code snippet generator to port the call to my C# app, and when I run on the app it does not work.

[C# response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9yE2.png)

The code snippet is:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://172.20.27.1/xxxxxx/xxxxxx");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Postman-Token", "1d9df75d-2c8f-4c92-b861-9f4291145846");
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");
request.AddParameter("multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW", "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Metas\"; filename=\"C:\\Users\\agufprad\\Desktop\\Pepillo\\FLEX_REMAN_CfgRec_Final_00-00-00-4D_20190311-102223_1010039188_7000AHB.xml\"\r\nContent-Type: application/xml\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Is there anything I am not seeing here?

Comment: There's no content in the file you're uploading in the snippet. Is that correct - it's an empty file?

Comment: Hello @Rup The file is filled with 123 lines of information.

Comment: What status code do you get in C#?

Comment: OK, but there isn't any file content in your C# snippet. There's nothing here that reads a file from disk to post: it just sends "Content-Type: application/xml\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary". The XML content should be between the second and third \r\n s. Maybe you should write your own RestSharp file upload POST, e.g. request.AddFile ?

Comment: Hey @meJustAndrew in C# I am getting a "completed" response status, on postman I receive an 200 OK status, but the response is different int C# and postman.

Comment: Great! But is it a 200? I suspect that you receive a 400 bad request on this. Is this the case?

Comment: It is a 406 Not Acceptable, mate

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare request from postman and non working c# application.  Make c# look like postman.

Answer (score 1):

**Can you export + upload the postman collection.  That would help a lot.**

A couple of things I see off the bat

1) You have a postman token header - why do you need this in C#?

2) Does none multi-part data work?

3) Are you sure content type is supposed to have the boundary data?

4) There is no file associated with the snippet.  Pretty sure you can't just AddParameter multi-part data.  Look for `AddFile`, which may be your issue.

5) Does an example off the web work?  Currently this looks like it would be a malformed multi-part request

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone for the responses, gave an idea of where to look.

Finally i added a header on the post method `request.AddHeader("Accept", "text/plain");`

And added the file `request.AddFile(fileName, Properties.Settings.Default.SaveRoute + fileName);`

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I would advice you remove any content-length param, postman-token, cookie param generated from the code generator on Postman, and it should work as its own specific request.

Remove

```
 request.AddHeader("Postman-Token", "1d9df75d-2c8f-4c92-b861-9f4291145846");
```